# The new default 'custom' Off-Topic close reason on per site metas makes no sense

Tags: support, close-reasons, per-site-meta

Per-site meta's get their own separate batch of custom close reasons from their respective main sites. This is awesome. Unfortunately, the default text is a little bit nonsensical.

> This question does not appear to be about on-topic, within the scope defined in the help center.

I too would like to see more questions about on-topic.

The default should probably read something like

> This question does not appear to be about $SiteName, within the scope defined in the help center.

(If, for some reason, the default cannot be changed, consider this a gentle nudge to all of you site-moderators!)

Comment: The help center link also gives the main sites scope as that's where the help center is hosted - perhaps the link should be to `help/whats-meta` instead?

Comment: I don't think this issue still occurs, as far as I can tell. Can anyone still reproduce this issue, or should it be marked as [status-completed] (or closed as no longer reproducible)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is not about on-topic, within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

Site moderators can fix this for their own sites by going to the **/admin/flags/close-as-off-topic** page of their meta site (any question → close → off-topic → edit these reasons) and changing the Default Off-Topic Close Reason to something like:

```
This question does not appear to be about [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com),
within the scope defined in the
[help center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).
```

(I preferred to link straight to the relevant page of the help center, rather than just the front hub.)

Comment: You can use `[main]` in there, but on sites that don't have a special name that is confusing. ("This question does not appear to be about [Physics] ...")

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `$Topic` variable for metas is set to "on topic":

[image]

Fun fact: I tried switching it to `$SiteName`, and I got this:

[image]

This is wrong too, it's the exact opposite of   the first rule of Meta Club.

Comment: What about the main site name? This should work

Comment: @JanDvorak Of course that works. I was just amused by the result of the OPs suggestion.  `$Topic` and `$SiteName`, when used in a close reason, get substituted accordingly